# Should Settings be inside Profile Screen?

Tags: buttons, ios, mobile-application, settings, profile

I'm working on a mobile app where I have a profile screen which tracks your stats from previous months on how long you've been meditating for. Should Settings go inside Profile or should I access settings from a different button next to Profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest if you have too **much data** **for the user profile then you have to add a setting button side to the profile**, in this case its better to separate the things, so that user can differentiate better.

but in case of you have **less date for the user then you can merge them together by adding some icon in interactive way** which will define that both(profile settings and general app settings) are under in the same icon

Here i add some of my work, hope it will help you better to work.

[image]